# Is it mandatory to login to Agora RTM Server while using Agora Chat SDK in Android App? If so, then how to login to RTM server in agora.io?

Tags: agora.io

I'm trying to implement Agora Chat SDK into my android application. Following the given documentation, I have tried to send Peer to Peer message but every time it showed INVALID_TOKEN_ERROR.
Please any suggestions will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you call mRtmClient.login(), you need to pass in the token as a parameter. To generate a token, you need to deploy a token server and get the token from the server. Here is the article about how to generate a RTM token from server: https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/token_server_rtm?platform=All%20Platforms.